# Problem in creating HyperlinkOrPicture columns in SharePoint using the Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am building an application consisting of Azure functions, working with the Graph API. A part of the code is creating columns in a SharePoint document library, just like described in the sample here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0

It works completely fine if I am creating text, datetime, boolean or number types of columns, but when I try to create a HyperlinkOrPicture column, I get the following error:

Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2022-05-10T12:37:54
request-id: xxx
client-request-id: xxx
ClientRequestId: xxx

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
                ColumnDefinition clLink = new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Name = "testLink",
                    DisplayName = "testLink",
                    HyperlinkOrPicture = new HyperlinkOrPictureColumn { IsPicture = false }
                };

                if (columns.Any(cl => String.Compare(cl.Name, clLink.Name, true) == 0) == false)
                {
                    await graphClient.Sites[_siteID].Lists[_listID].Columns
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(clLink);
                }
```

The Graph package I am using has the version 4.27.0.

What am I doing incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that create or update Hyperlink column is not supported. You can upvote the feature request here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-to-update-of-sharepoint-listitem-with-hyperlink-field/idi-p/3021504

Comment: Thanks, that might be the problem. I upvoted the feature request.